# Multiple border crossings between Canada and USA

Tags: usa, canada, borders, b1-b2-visas

I am visiting Canada from Romania on visitor visa, I have a USA B1/B2 visa with multiple entries (from Romania also) valid for 10 years.

I am planing to visit few friends in the USA, but I am planing to visit them on different times. Can I cross the border a few times? Is there a certain amount of time between the crossings? How long I am allowed to stay each time in USA?

Comment: I think that all answers to your question are written on your visa. A multiple-entry visa, by definition, allows to enter multiple times. Then for the rest, how long is your visa valid? What type is your visa? B1?

Comment: B1/B2 and I have a 10years visa

Comment: What's your citizenship?

Comment: Romanian citizen

Comment: It sounds to me like you'll be fine.  To be on the safe side, have documentation of your plans to fly back to Romania, as well as proof of your finances, each time you cross the border.  You don't need to show it unless you are asked, however.

Comment: The US B1 visa gives you access in six month chunks (check the I94 they give you for the exact date). Make sure your Canadian visa is also multiple entry

Answer (score 1):

1) Having a multiple entry visa allows you repeat visits as long as the visa is valid so yes you can (technically) visit more than once.

2) If granted entry, you will be given an I-94 form with a date on it by which you must leave the US. That determines your duration of stay, more on that [here](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/880/kw/i94).

3) A visa only gives you the right to request entry at a country's border, the decision remains with border officials. It will be up to them to decide whether or not you're traveling too frequently. In the past you could keep the I-94 in your passport if you intended to travel again before it expired, I'm not sure that's still applicable but I couldn't find anything about a minimum duration between stays

Here's the [Department of State](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/general/frequently-asked-questions.html) on multiple-entry visas:

> A visa must be valid at the time a traveler seeks admission to the United  States, but the expiration date of the visa (validity period/length of time the visa can be used) has no relation to the length of time a temporary visitor may be authorized by the Department of Homeland Security to remain in the United States. Persons holding visas valid for multiple entries may make repeated trips to the United States, for travel for the same purpose, as long as the visa has not expired, and the traveler has done nothing to become ineligible to enter the United States, at port-of-entry.